# Regular expression: Should not start with 5 digits (or more) in a row

Tags: regex

I need to generate a regular expression to validate that the string does not start with 5 digits.

```
NOT VALID: 12345testing123asd

VALID: 1234testing1234
testing12345
testing
```

I tried to get the first five chars `^.{0,5}` but I do not know hot to add the restriction of `\D` to those first 5 chars

Also, I tried with this `[^0-9][^0-9][^0-9][^0-9][^0-9]` but I do not know how to do to include the strings that starts with 4 or less numbers

Could you please help me with this? I am a rookie :(

Comment: Is `123456testing` valid? This is important to know here.

Comment: Just `^(?!\d{5}).+$` possibly. Or maybe `^\d{0,4}\D.*$` does the job too.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, not it is not, because starts with 5 digits (or more) You are right. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your RegExp flavor of choice supports negative lookaheads, this pattern will match if the string is *valid* (does not start with 5 or more consecutive digits):

```
^(?!\d{5,})
```

[<sup>Regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/1ScFH9/1)

Matches:

- 1234testing1234
- testing12345
- testing

Does not match:

- 12345testing123asd